# using function expression with callback function instated of arrow function

Tags: javascript, binding, callback

I have this code below works pretty well when I use arrow function as a callback function

```
var getNumber = function (argument, callback) {   
callback(argument - 1);
} 
getNumber(10, (x)=>{
console.log(x); // x = 9
});
```

now when I want to change the arrow function to function expression in the code below.

```
var getNumber = function (argument, callback) {
callback(argument - 1);
}
getNumber(10, action(x)); // x is not defined 
function action(x){
console.log(x);
}
```

sadly I got error says x is not defined.

Comment: because you aren't passing a function expression, that is you calling a function named `action`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second snippet you're not passing the function, you're calling the function and then passing the result as a parameter. You want

```
getNumber(10, action); // x is not defined 
function action(x){
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try running the following code

```js
var getNumber = function (argument, callback) {
callback(argument - 1);
}
getNumber(10, action); // x is not defined 
function action(x){
console.log(x);
}
```

you were calling action(x) whereas it expected a function, there is no value of x where you were calling action(x) hence it raised the error

Answer (score 1):

```
var getNumber = function (argument, callback) {
 callback(argument - 1);
}

function action(x){
 console.log(x);
}

getNumber(10, action); // pass callback function, not result of the call
```